# Change in Reputation

Tags: support

Till yesterday my reputation was 4769. Today I notice its gone down to 4701.
I understand reputation can go down because of various reasons [unaccept an answer, unvote, down vote etc].
But I would like to know if something on scoring & calculation has changed.

Comment: p.s. mine just dropped from 9025 to 8891, due to a recalc.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Occasionally, the reputation numbers in the system may be **recalculated**.

In such cases it is possible for reputation to decrease if you had, for instance, answered a question, had some up-votes on your answer, and the question were subsequently deleted (for instance, as off-topic, not a real question, etc.)

The recalculation doesn't count up-votes on deleted questions and answers.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks - good to know!